# Jsoup.connect Throws error

Tags: android

I want to parse html pages and extract data but when I tried to connect with Jsoup it throws errors.
when I connected using httpclient  [String s = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");]
there was no problem  the html page content I was able to store into a string. But with Jsoup I am not able to do it.Am I making some error?

```
    package com.example.flashcardsdemo;

import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

//import com.example.flashcards.MainActivity.Gethtml;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context=this;
        Gethtml Ght = new Gethtml();
        Ght.execute();
    }

    public class Gethtml extends AsyncTask {
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        String UrlLink = "http://en.wikipedia.org/";
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            dialog.setTitle("Loading");
            dialog.setMessage("Html....");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(UrlLink);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                StatusLine line = response.getStatusLine();
                int statuscode = line.getStatusCode();
                if (statuscode != 200) {
                    return null;
                }

                Document doc  = Jsoup.connect(UrlLink).get();

            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("Error", e.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    }   
}
```

LogCat image:
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6bDv.png
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBxUB.png

Comment: From the images it seems like you have not imported the Jsoup library into your project. It says that the class definition is absent.

Comment: No I have imported the jsoup lib..

Comment: It has not been imported properly, thats why the error is there. Try importing the jar file again.

Comment: I have did what u said I get error again and have displayed my full code above with logcat image plz check it.

Comment: I have did what u said but again I get error. I have displayed my full code above plz check it.

Answer (score 0):

Make certain your JSoup jar file is exported along with the rest of your code. Do the following

Right click Project

Java Build Path

Order and Export

Check the box next your Jsoup jar entry.

Then reload the app onto your emulator or device.

You should also clean your project

Right click Project->
Click Android Tools->
Click Fix Project Properties
And Click Project
Clean

If it still doesnt work then do the following:

Remove the older export and create a libs/ directory in your project (as a peer of src/, res/, etc.) if you do not already have one. Then, put the JSoup JAR in the libs/ directory. This will both add it to your build path and include its contents in your APK file.